# OpenCL compiler is sensitive to Windows 10 user profile?

Tags: compiler-errors, opencl

Long story short, I use darktable on Windows 10, which uses OpenCL library. Behind the scene darktable will use OpenCL compiler to compiler the kernels (a little more details is https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/issues/3717). Unfortunately I got errors

```
C:\Program Files\darktable\bin>darktable-cltest.exe
0.094021 [opencl_init] opencl related configuration options:
0.096021 [opencl_init]
0.097022 [opencl_init] opencl: 1
0.099022 [opencl_init] opencl_library: ''
0.100022 [opencl_init] opencl_memory_requirement: 768
0.101022 [opencl_init] opencl_memory_headroom: 300
0.104022 [opencl_init] opencl_device_priority: '*/!0,*/*/*'
0.106024 [opencl_init] opencl_mandatory_timeout: 200
0.108024 [opencl_init] opencl_size_roundup: 16
0.110025 [opencl_init] opencl_async_pixelpipe: 0
0.111024 [opencl_init] opencl_synch_cache: 0
0.113025 [opencl_init] opencl_number_event_handles: 25
0.114025 [opencl_init] opencl_micro_nap: 1000
0.115025 [opencl_init] opencl_use_pinned_memory: 0
0.116025 [opencl_init] opencl_use_cpu_devices: 0
0.117026 [opencl_init] opencl_avoid_atomics: 0
0.119027 [opencl_init]
0.120026 [opencl_init] found opencl runtime library 'OpenCL.dll'
0.123027 [opencl_init] opencl library 'OpenCL.dll' found on your system and loaded
0.192043 [opencl_init] found 1 platform
0.194043 [opencl_init] found 1 device
0.195044 [opencl_init] device 0 `Ellesmere' supports image sizes of 16384 x 16384
0.198044 [opencl_init] device 0 `Ellesmere' allows GPU memory allocations of up to 4048MB
[opencl_init] device 0: Ellesmere
     GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE:          8192MB
     MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE:      256
     MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS: 3
     MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES:      [ 1024 1024 1024 ]
     DRIVER_VERSION:           2906.10
     DEVICE_VERSION:           OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (2906.10)
0.450101 [opencl_init] options for OpenCL compiler: -cl-mad-enable  -DAMD=1 -I"C:\Program Files\darktable\share\darktable\kernels"
0.455102 [opencl_init] compiling program `demosaic_ppg.cl' ..
0.457103 [opencl_load_program] loaded cached binary program from file `C:\Users\Hardy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\darktable\cached_kernels_for_Ellesmere\demosaic_ppg.cl.bin'
0.464104 [opencl_load_program] successfully loaded program from `C:\Program Files\darktable\share\darktable\kernels\demosaic_ppg.cl'
0.469105 [opencl_build_program] could not build program: -11
0.471105 [opencl_build_program] BUILD STATUS: -2
0.473106 BUILD LOG:
0.474106 Error: The binary is incorrect or incomplete. Finalization to ISA couldn't be performed.

0.478107 [opencl_init] failed to compile program `demosaic_ppg.cl'!
0.480107 [opencl_init] FINALLY: opencl is NOT AVAILABLE on this system.
0.482108 [opencl_init] initial status of opencl enabled flag is OFF.

press any key to exit
```

But when I log in to the same computer with another user profile/account, it just works. So it must be environmental issues somewhere. I have no experience with OpenCL, so I'd like to get some insight how shall I "clean" my profile to fix OpenCL compiler?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an environment issue, it's a cache issue.

Darktable caches compiles OpenCL kernels and then it tries to load them next time, to speed up things. Unfortunately for some reason you have a cache which is incorrect for your device (perhaps you updated your system/drivers/ something and darktable missed it). You need to clear the Darktable kernel cache. From the log it seems it's in this directory:

```
C:\Users\Hardy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\darktable\cached_kernels_for_Ellesmere
```

Just go there and delete all content.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug from darktable, I used a higher version this issue is gone.